# Can we get the answers to this question merged into a single CW answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

So, the question "[What monsters are depicted on the 4.0 DM Screen?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/what-monsters-are-depicted-on-the-4-0-dm-screen?rq=1)" has 3 answers that each contribute a bit of answer to the question and collectively answer it.  Rather than 3 separate answers, I think they should be appended one after the other into a single answer, since that's the entire point of the Community Wiki option.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I've soured on CW answers after [my brief dalliance](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6213/23970) with them. I'd be more interested in seeing you assemble the parts into one comprehensive answer, with attribution liberally sprinkled about. Nobody's likely to accuse a top-20 name in the reputation league of trying to pad their stats, and they'd be wrong if they did.

I don't think either way's right or wrong in this case, though. That there ^^ is what my instinct would be if I were looking at such a thing.

Comment: I had that instinct, but then I was like 'isn't this what CW is for?'.  Fair enough, though, I might go collate them.

Comment: Looks like greener beat you to it =)

Answer (score 1):

I agree this seems like a decent use case for Community Wiki. I'd also like to see a comprehensive answer that's verifiable and not just "maybe it's this?".

I've posted a Community Wiki answer with numbering: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120494/1204

Thanks to a later edit by TDW, #2 is the only one left without a conclusive answer. If anyone knows for sure what that one is, feel free to add it in.

(This isn't endorsing this as a scenarion which others should use CW as well; I just chose to do so in this case because I can.)

Comment: Not to be contrarian, but... I'd suggest that the answer you posted is a significant improvement over any of the existing ones, shows work of your own, and really does "deserve" to have the rep go to the author. But again, not a strong "right" or "wrong" result, methinks.

Comment: @nitsua60 That's a valid concern, though also I'm 30k and even have this spiffy diamond, and either one alone means I don't feel much need to get rep anymore. That made it a pretty easy decision to just make it CW so that people could go make sure the answer was awesome with the last bits missing. This is a fairly exceptional situation though for that judgement call to come up. :P